# Git local branch does not recognize pulled changes

Tags: git, merge, branch, git-remote

I was working on a local branch lets call it "dev", other team-members pushed new content to remote's master. So I commited the branch, checked-out local master and pulled from the remote one, then I switched back to dev branch and merged from local master, but I didn't see any changes (and I know there are changes) in the files. 
Git says that nothing needs to be merged and everything is clean, but in my local master I have stuff that does not appear in my dev branch.

I would like to do that merge somehow.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Run `git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all` and tell me weather your master has any commit that is not there in dev branch.

Comment: Also, what output did your pull give?

Comment: @MudassirRazvi No. It seems like that the dev branch is ahead the master by some commits.
The output was regullar: "Merge made by recursive." It did merge with the local master

Comment: That means your master has nothing new that dev doesn't have.

Either your pull didn't work or you somehow already have the changes pushed by team.

Comment: But I see the differences when I change from the dev branch to master :)
How can I fix this, so that git will recognize that the dev branch will be updated with the changes?

Answer (score 0):

Try if this helps:

1. `git checkout master` (Assuming master has changes you want)
2. `git checkout -b dev1`
3. `git merge dev`

This must do the trick!

Comment: Again, didn't work... :/
On the new branch I just see the changes from the original branch and I don't see the new data that I pulled. Frustrating. Maybe I should do the merge manually? And if yes, how to it?

Comment: If your master has changes that you want, you are branching from it and then merging dev and still you dont see changes only means you are deleting them in dev of something of that sort.

Comment: But still, when I merge them, the new methods from master should appear to the dev branch, no?